# Getting "TimeoutException: Message" while running the Python test file in Selenium-hub (created using docker-compose)

Tags: python, docker, selenium

I am trying to run my automation test case (Written in Python) on the Selenium Grid (created with the docker-compose.yml file). When I run the "docker-compose up -d" command, the Grid opens up successfully and works as expected. However, it keeps throwing the TimeoutException: Message when I run the test.py file **(I am using a corporate laptop connected via VPN issued by my organization)**.If I run the test.py file without the DesiredCapabilities , it works absolutely fine. I am using the Selenium grid/hub for the **first time** on my system (Windows 10).

I have tried my level best to search for the answer on google & stackoverflow, yet, here I am! Could you please help me with your feedback as where am I making the mistake?

test.py

```
import time
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


class TestLogin(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        base_url = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurywelcome.php"
        host = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=host, desired_capabilities=caps)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get(base_url)

    def test_login(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        user_name = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "userName")))
        user_name.send_keys('ralphsin')
        print("Entered UserId")
        time.sleep(2)

        password = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
        password.send_keys('abc123')
        print("Entered Password")
        time.sleep(2)

        log_in = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@alt='Sign-In']")))
        log_in.click()
        print("Clicked on Sign-In button!")
        time.sleep(2)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
    hub:
        image: selenium/hub:3.141.59
        ports: 
            - 4444:4444
    chrome:
        image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59
        depends_on: 
            - hub
        environment: 
            - HUB_HOST=hub
            - HUB_PORT=4444
    firefox:
        image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59
        depends_on: 
            - hub
        environment: 
            - HUB_HOST=hub
            - HUB_PORT=4444
```

Error Message

```
C:\Users\rsingh99\Desktop\WebDevelopment_and_Automation\Selenium_Projects\test_selenium>pytest -v test.py
=========================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.1, pytest-5.0.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- c:\users\rsingh99\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\rsingh99\Desktop\WebDevelopment_and_Automation\Selenium_Projects\test_selenium
plugins: ordering-0.6
collected 1 item

test.py::TestLogin::test_login FAILED                                                                                                                                [100%]

================================================================================ FAILURES =================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________ TestLogin.test_login ___________________________________________________________________________

self = <test.TestLogin testMethod=test_login>

    def test_login(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
>       user_name = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "userName")))

test.py:22:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait (session="54f19a6e911494f8fd102e2f51cb4104")>
method = <selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located object at 0x000002925F4AE4E0>, message = ''

    def until(self, method, message=''):
        """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
        return value is not False."""
        screen = None
        stacktrace = None

        end_time = time.time() + self._timeout
        while True:
            try:
                value = method(self._driver)
                if value:
                    return value
            except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
                screen = getattr(exc, 'screen', None)
                stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
            time.sleep(self._poll)
            if time.time() > end_time:
                break
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

..\..\..\..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:80: TimeoutException
======================================================================== 1 failed in 11.75 seconds ========================================================================
```

Comment: Nice job with this question - good details.  When I try to curl the url you gave me, I get a 406 response that will never contain that element you're waiting for.  Is that the correct URL?  Maybe selenium is legitimately waiting for the 10 seconds you told it to, for a DOM element from the url, that will never come?

Comment: @DanielFarrell - Thank you for looking into it. The URL is correct and works fine locally. I just removed the DesiredCapabilities and used "self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()" and got the response as "1 passed in 17.58 seconds". Yet, I will try and use some other website to check the response. Thanks again.

Comment: @RakeshSingh the problem is what mentioned above. The time exception means that the element is not visible and after waiting 'X' seconds the test is failing. Can you increase the waiting time to more seconds even a minute to check if the problem is the time? Because if after 1 min the element is going to be visible, then it's delay - time issue. In any other case means that the element was not visible for more than 1 min which means that it is not loaded at all (or in general not a time issue). Please, try the case with the time (to exclude it) and if it's still failing to ping us here again.

Comment: @dpapadopoulos and DaniellFarrell - First of all let me apologies, as I did miss an extremely (I don't know how did I forget about this?) important piece of information. I am using a corporate laptop connected through a VPN issued by my organization. Does it have to do anything with the proxy settings? As far as docker is concerned, I do use proxy settings to bypass it and pull the images or work inside a container using the bash/sh.

Comment: If you are having proxy enabled BEFORE and WHILE you are running the dock then it's fine. Though, there is a chance that some proxy configs need to include passwords into the dock config file. This is something that I can't really help since I don't know your proxy manager and how it is interacting. But most of the time when the proxy is running you don't have to do anything else. It seems like cannot even go to the given link. Try this too: print browser.current_url in order to check if you are going into this URL.

Comment: @dpapadopoulos - I did change the website to google.com and added the command to print the current url. As per the output received, it does connect to the correct URL (test1.py::TestSearchBox::test_search_box https://google.com/ FAILED). However, it still throws the same error (selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:). I really have no idea as what is causing the issue. I will keep digging the almighty google, let's hope that I will find some sort of solution. Once again thanks for looking into it.

Comment: That's weird indeed. All I can say in that case is something fundamental, check the versions between chromedriver, chrome browser, and selenium. Many times such issues are hiding behind initial configuration steps.

Comment: Ahh did you allow the PC to sleep?